# flask to javascript, sending json, running into invalid syntax error

Tags: javascript, python, json

I ran into this error while trying to send a pandas to_json object to front end using flask. the codes and errors look like this:

```
df_higg_msi_scored_manual = pd.read_csv(r'static/CSVFiles/higg_msi_scored_manual.csv')    
materials = df_higg_msi_scored_manual.iloc[:33, 3]
material = materials.to_json(orient="values")
return render_template('/impacttool.html', material = material)
```

```
var user = JSON.parse('{{brand | tojson | safe}}');
```

and this is the error that pops up no matter how valid the resulting json file is:

[image]

depending on which json i send to the front end, i get either unexpected number or unexpected token, with unexpected token always matching the first alphabet of the first string in json. Could someone please help me figure this out? I've even tried print(material) on flask, then copied the exact json that was printed to the console, assigned that to a variable and sent it to the front end and it worked fine! but for some reason when i do to_json and assign it directly to a variable it throws this error. If someone knows how to fix it  I would love to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript try to see what
`console.log('{{brand | tojson | safe}}')`
gets you because maybe you're trying to turn JSON data into JSON data so maybe also consider removing the `| to json` part of the variable call

Edit: calling variables doesn't work in files other than HTML files so try parsing the variable directly in the HTML file like so:

```
<script>
var user = JSON.parse('{{brand | tojson | safe}}')
</script>
```

or you could add it to a variable in the HTML file then parse it in the javascript file like so:

*filename*.html:

```
<script>
var jsondata = '{{brand | tojson | safe}}'
</script>
```

*filename*.js

```
var user = JSON.parse(jsondata)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution thanks to RaphSinai, it was because the {{ brands | tojson }} was formatted with extra double quotes as "[whatever...]" instead of just the [], so I changed the code from material = materials.to_json(orient="values") to json.loads(material = materials.to_json(orient="values")) and it worked fine.